# Injective mapping

Tags: functions

I am reading about manifolds in the larger context of Cosmology. I came across the definition of injective mapping. The writer defines injective mapping as one in which one element of M maps to no more than one element of N. He further points out that $\phi(x)=e^x$ is an injective mapping. I can see how one element of $x$ maps to no more than one element of $\phi(x)$ but how it can it be less than one? I assuming that the definition of injective mapping allows the condition where one element of M does not map to any element of N.

Comment: I suggest reading through [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) page, the illustrations are particularly informative.

Comment: "one element of M maps to no more than one element of N" is part of the definition of _function_.

Comment: I was confused about the idea if there can be some element in the image that has no mapping in the domain i.e. an injective mapping can have no element in the domain.

Comment: I think I figured out my confusion. For a mapping $\phi: M \rightarrow N$ I have been looking at elements of M mapping to at most one in N. In reality, the definition of injective says, each N only maps to at most one in M. So when we look at $\phi: x \rightarrow e^x$, every value of $e^x$ corresponds to at most one $x$ but there is one member of $e^x$ that has no counter-part in $x$ and that is 0. There is no $x$ which makes $e^x$ equal to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the definition of an injective map. In order to get a map one needs that each element is only sent to one element. A map $f  \colon M \rightarrow N$ is injective if every element of $N$ has at most one preimage. Consider for example:

[image]

The element $3$ is ”hit“ more than one times by our map. Therefore the map I drew is not injective. Injective maps are maps such that each element is ”hit“ at most one times under the map.

Comment: Doesn't "at most once" mean the same as no more than once? That there is an element in the domain that has no mapping in the image?

Comment: I am thinking of these as "injective: no greater than one" and "surjective: no less than one".

Comment: I think I figured out my confusion. For a mapping $\phi: M \rightarrow N$ I have been looking at elements of M mapping to at most one in N. In reality, the definition of injective says, each N only maps to at most one in M. So when we look at $\phi: x \rightarrow e^x$, every value of $e^x$ corresponds to at most one $x$ but there is one member of $e^x$ that has no counter-part in $x$ and that is 0. There is no $x$ which makes $e^x$ equal to zero.

Comment: Your formulation is still wrong, but I think you are basically understanding it now. You cannot reverse an arbitrary map and consider this as a map from $N$ to $M$. Intuitively, that works though. If you are reversing the arrows (which does not give a map in general) then every element of $N$ is sent to at most one element of $M$. To avoid this reversing part I was speaking elements of $N$ being ”hit“ at most once. Yes, exactly. That depends on the codomain of the map. If the codomian consists of all real numbers that are bigger or equal to zero, then you will not find a corresponding $x$.

Comment: But if there is a map $ \phi: M \rightarrow N$ and I say that map is injective then, by definition, for each element of N there is at most one element in M. Is this correct? Of course, such a mapping is not reversible unless it is also surjective.

Comment: Yes, but you should say: For each element $n \in N$ there is at most one element in $m \in M$ such that $\phi(m) = n$. The condition depends on the map and therefore you should mention the map you are considering.